# Ruby on Rails - run unit tests in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible  to run tests only from one subfolder?

Something like this:

```
ruby -I"lib:test" test/functional/api/*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to find a way to run multiple unit tests in a specific directory and you're not using RSpec...

In that case, you can create a task in a Rakefile and run it from command line. This page  [Rake::TestTask](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html) will tell you how to create such a file. You're file is going to look something like this:

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/functional/api/*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

And then run:

```
rake test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use rspec you can do this

```
rspec ./spec/models/
```

for a folder

and this

```
rspec ./spec/models/car_spec.rb
```

for one file

and this

```
rspec ./spec/models/car_spec.rb:34
```

for the test on line 34